# TestNG XML cannot find test class in package (java)

Tags: java, xml, testng

I am using testNG with IntelliJ, and I am trying to set up an XML file in order to control the sequence of my test cases (among other things). However, when I try to put my class name into the XML, it does not recognise it. I read somewhere that it needs to be in a package, so I created a package for my tests, but it still does not recognise either of the package or the class. The error it gives me is **cannot resolve class BotIncidentTest**

 Here is my XML file:

```
<test name="everything">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.BotIncidentTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AqZb.jpg)

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your project folder structure. If your package is called test, your are not doing anything wrong imho. The compiled classes should be in the target directory.

Comment: Hi, as I am new to stack overflow I am not yet allowed to post screenshots, however there is a link to my project structure under the code block. Sorry for the inconvenience :/

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that my testng.xml was in the wrong place. I'm not sure why this was a problem, but it was in the highest level of folders, and when I moved it into my test folder in which my test package exists, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect test class to check out if you are using correct package name (that your class belongs to). As Xwris Stoixeia said, if *test* is the name of the package that it belongs to then you're doing it right.
Anyway, you can refer to this [website](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testngxml-example-to-execute-with-class-names) to recheck your process.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean at the top of the class, there is `package test;`? In which case it is named correctly. The thing that is so confusing to me is that every resource I've checked says I'm doing it right but I still get this error as if my package/class doesn't exist.